# asp.net, datalist image binding from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am trying to retrieve an image from a folder and display it in my datalist, but unfortunately the image is not being displayed.

When I run the code and inspect the element it shows me the right path, but the image does not show.

**asp code**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2" rowspan="6">
                    <img src= "<%# Eval(("Photo")) %>" />               
                </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**C# code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;



namespace CARSEZEE2015
{
    public partial class WebForm3: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server name;Initial Catalog=catalogname;User ID=id;Password=password");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from DB";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            DataList1.DataSource = dt;
            DataList1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
'
```

Comment: I formatted your code, and it looks like you're missing a lot of your asp code...

Comment: Thank you JNYRanger ,i have just pasted the main datalist asp code above just to avoid confusion and clutter

Answer (score 0):

you should save images path and names in database:

for example "images/folder1/image1.jpg"

```
<img src= '<%# Bind("imgtp","~/{0}") %>' />
```